# An affine transformation, and its effect on a curve and a polynomial.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-curves, change-of-basis, change-of-variable

Suppose $(u,v) = A(x,y)$ is affine transformation.

Where $u = ax + by + e$, and $v = cx + dy + f$ , and the inverse transformation given by $x = a'u + b'v + e'$ and $y = c'u + d'v + f'$.

Suppose further that $C$ is a curve given by the polynomial equation $P(x,y) = 0$.

I am wondering how to interpret the image of $C$ under the affine map $A$.

It seems that $(q,r)$ is a point of the curve $C$ (and so $P(q,r) = 0$) if and only if $A(q,r) = (aq + br + e, cq + dr + f)$ is a point of the curve defined by the "transformed polynomial" $P(u,v) = P(a'u + b'v + e',c'u + d'v + f')$.

Is this correct?

Comment: Does [your previous questiion](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3075468/265466) not answer this, too?